# Reference request for lemma of Castelnuovo

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

While reading a paper by Ciliberto and Lazarsfeld ("*On the uniqueness of certain linear series on some classes of curves*") I came across a lemma of Castelnuovo used in the paper. The lemma says that if a divisor $D$ (on a smooth projective curve) is in $t_i$-uniform position with respect to a $g^{r_i}_{d_i}$ (i.e. degree $t_i$ divisors in $D$ impose independent conditions on the $g^{r_i}_{d_i}$), then for $t := \sum_i(t_i-1) + 1$ and $V:= \sum_i g^{r_i}_{d_i}$ we have:

- if $t < \text{deg}(D)$ then $D$ is in $t$-uniform position with
  respect to $V$
- if $t \geq \text{deg}(D)$ then $D$ imposes independent
  conditions on $V$

where the sum $V$ is the *minimal sum of the linear series* defined as the linear series associated to the image (in the appropriate global sections space) under the product map on sections.

The authors indicate that a proof of the lemma can be found in the paper "*Alcune applicazioni di un classico procedimento di Castelnuovo*" by Ciliberto. Unfortunately, after extensive searching online, I cannot find this paper. Nor can I find a proof of the lemma anywhere else.

> Does anyone know where I might find some version of this paper or at
>   least a proof of the lemma?

Comment: Here at least is a little more complete reference.  Alcune applicazioni di un classico procedimento di Castelnuovo, Seminario di Geometria, Universita
di Bologna (1982-83), 17-43.  Maybe you could email Ciro.  cilibert@mat.uniroma2.it